# PHP MySQL ElasticSearch migration query OR

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I cannot figure out the following:

A database with address fields (country, county, city) and an "operate" field, options: locally, nationally internationally

I want to find matches based on location and the "operate" status. So I am basically searching for how to use MySQL OR in ElasticSearch. To my understanding this is "should".

So, any entry that operates internationally should be in the results, any entry that operates nationally in the same country and any entry that operates locally in the same county regardless which city is selected

Just as a test case, I tried several things among which the following:

```
$arrayinternationally[] = array('match' => array('operate' => 'internationally'));

$arrayNationally[] = array('match' => array('operate' => 'nationally'));
$arrayNationally[] = array('match' => array('country' => '60'));

$arrayLocally[] = array('match' => array('operate' => 'locally'));
$arrayLocally[] = array('match' => array('country' => 'UK'));
$arrayLocally[] = array('match' => array('county' => '60'));

$params = [
    'index' => 'bzlistings',

    'body' => [
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 80, 
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'should' => $arrayinternationally
                    ]
                ],
                'should' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'should' => $arrayNationally
                    ]
                ],
                'should' => [
                    'bool' => [
                        'should' => $arrayLocally
                    ]
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

Those entries in another country with "operate" set to "internationally", are not included, which is wrong.

How can this be done in ElasticSearch?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Could you write here how are you doing this search on SQL?

Comment: We migrated to ElasticSearch before changing the search query, but in MySQL it would look something like this: SELECT * FROM bzListings WHERE (operate='internationally') OR (operate='nationally' AND country= 'UK') OR (operate='locally' AND country='UK' AND county='60')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is something wrong with the bool queries. Could you test with following query :

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'bzlistings',
    'body' => [
        'from' => 0,
        'size' => 80, 
        'query' => [
            'bool' => [
                'should' => [
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => $arrayinternationally
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => $arrayNationally
                        ]
                    ],
                    [
                        'bool' => [
                            'must' => $arrayLocally
                        ]
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

But I think, in your case, inner bools need to be `must` instead of `should`. Also, I recommend that if you are looking for exact matching, you can use `term` query instead of `match`.

Typically, the bool query structure is something like the below :

```
GET sample-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {},
        {}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping! This does return more results but not accurately. entries in a different country with "operate" set to "nationally" are also includes in the results.

Comment: Yes, I know. I already mentioned this. You need to change "shoulds" with "must". `'should' => $arrayinternationally` need to be as `'must' => $arrayinternationally`. And `'should' => $arrayNationally` need to be `'must' => $arrayNationally`, etc.

Comment: Let me change the answer according to your query.

Comment: So now, test it again.